# owl carousel last dot cant be set to active

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hope this is not a common issue and i'm asking a silly question here (i haven't found any info about it while searching).

I'm using the owl slider script (v 2.0.0) based on jquery (v 1.11.3).
The dot navigation works just fine as long as the number of elements total divided by the number of elements to be shown on the screen (option 'items') is an Integer.
If not (e.g. 8 elements total and 3 should be visible on the screen) the last dot will never get the active-class when clicked but always the dot next to it.

I don't get any errors in the JS-console.

The HTML and JavaScript code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>OWL Slider v2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../libs/owl.carousel.2.0.0/assets/owl.carousel.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../libs/owl.carousel.2.0.0/assets/owl.theme.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../libs/owl.carousel.2.0.0/owl.carousel.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="owl-example" class="owl-carousel">
        <div> Your Content 1</div>
        <div> Your Content 2</div>
        <div> Your Content 3</div>
        <div> Your Content 4</div>
        <div> Your Content 5</div>
        <div> Your Content 6</div>
        <div> Your Content 7</div>
        <div> Your Content 8</div>
        <div> Your Content 9</div>
    </div>
    <div id="owl-example2" class="owl-carousel">
        <div> Your Content 1</div>
        <div> Your Content 2</div>
        <div> Your Content 3</div>
        <div> Your Content 4</div>
        <div> Your Content 5</div>
        <div> Your Content 6</div>
        <div> Your Content 7</div>
        <div> Your Content 8</div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            /* init 1st slider using default settings */
            $("#owl-example").owlCarousel({
                items:3,
            });

            /* init 2nd slider using default settings */
            $("#owl-example2").owlCarousel({
                items:3,
            });

        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Thank you in advance for any hints.

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me with version 1.3.3 (latest Firefox). Are you using a beta, since you say it's 2.0.0?

Comment: on the homepage it states "2.0.0-beta.2.4"
(http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/)
so well i guess it's in fact a BETA

Comment: Then I suggest you try with the latest stable version and - you probably don't want a beta in your live system...

Comment: The reason we uses version 2.0.0 according to the coworker who worked on the project previously, version 1.3.3  has issues with automatically adjusting the with of the slider elements when resizing the window. I'll see how we can fix this then instead. Thanks for the hints

Comment: I find a working example in github issue #1120.